# Updating multiple element styles using querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to allow a user to update certain css properties on a page, specifically within the footer element, by submitting an html form with drop downs selectors. However, my jquery (which i don't know well) isn't doing the trick.  I suspect it has something to do with querySelectorAll, but I'm not sure why. The first style, that of footer background, does successfully update on form subit.

HTML Form:

```
<form id="styleform">
    <div>Background:</div>
    <div>
        <select id="footerbgd">                 
            <option value="#404040">Dark Grey</option>
            <option value="#7B7B7B">Mid Grey</option>
            <option value="#C5C5C5">Light Grey</option>
            <option value="#E5E5E5">Lighter Grey</option> 
            <option value="#F4F4F4">Lightest Grey</option>
            <option value="#ffffff">White</option>
        </select>           
    </div>      
    <div>Text Link:</div>
    <div>
        <select id="footertextlink">                    
            <option value="#404040">Dark Grey</option>
            <option value="#7B7B7B">Mid Grey</option>
            <option value="#C5C5C5">Light Grey</option>
            <option value="#E5E5E5">Lighter Grey</option> 
            <option value="#F4F4F4">Lightest Grey</option>
            <option value="#ffffff">White</option>
        </select>           
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Change Colors">
</form>
<footer>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>text link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>text link 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

Here's my js:

```
$( "#styleform" ).on('submit',function( event ) {
        var Fbgd = document.getElementById("footerbgd").value;
        var Ftextlink = document.getElementById("footertextlink").value;
        document.querySelector("footer").style.background = Fbgd;
        document.querySelectorAll("footer li a").style.color = Ftextlink;
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't ``event.preventDefault()`` be at the top?

Comment: @Crowes general practice is to put it at the top, but it makes no difference to the logic flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a collection, so you need to loop through it and call `style.color` on each element individually. To do this you could use `forEach()`:

```
document.querySelectorAll("footer li a").forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.color = Ftextlink;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Trying to use the values with cast value as HTMLElement                               `document.querySelectorAll("footer li a").forEach(function(el) {
  (value as HTMLElement).el.style.color = Ftextlink;
});  `